# Android - android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I got this error message state `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment`. Is it because of i'm not extending it into `fragment` in `MessagesFragment`? By the way, my app using `TabHost`.

FirstFragment.java

```
package com.xxxxx.yyyyy.match;

import com.xxxxx.yyyyy.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    public FirstFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.first_fragment,
                null);
    return v;
    }
}
```

first_fragment.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".FirstFragment" >

<fragment 
        android:name="com.xxxxx.yyyyy.chat.MessagesFragment"
        android:id="@+id/msg_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

MessagesFragment.java

```
package com.xxxxx.yyyyy.chat;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import com.xxxxx.yyyyy.R;
import com.xxxxx.yyyyy.library.chat.DataProvider;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.app.LoaderManager;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MessagesFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    private static final DateFormat[] df = new DateFormat[] {
        DateFormat.getDateInstance(), DateFormat.getTimeInstance()};

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    private Date now;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }   

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        now = new Date();

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), 
                R.layout.chat_list_item, 
                null, 
                new String[]{DataProvider.COL_MSG, DataProvider.COL_AT}, 
                new int[]{R.id.text1, R.id.text2},
                0);

        adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {

            @Override
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
                switch(view.getId()) {
                case R.id.text1:
                    LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) view.getParent().getParent();
                    if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataProvider.COL_FROM)) == null) {
                        root.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                        root.setPadding(50, 10, 10, 10);
                    } else {
                        root.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                        root.setPadding(10, 10, 50, 10);
                    }
                    break;

                case R.id.text2:
                    TextView tv = (TextView) view;
                    tv.setText(getDisplayTime(cursor.getString(columnIndex)));
                    return true;                    
                }
                return false;
            }
        });     

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }   

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        getListView().setDivider(null);

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(DataProvider.COL_EMAIL, mListener.getProfileEmail());
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, args, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        public String getProfileEmail();
    }

    private String getDisplayTime(String datetime) {
        try {
            Date dt = sdf.parse(datetime);
            if (now.getYear()==dt.getYear() && now.getMonth()==dt.getMonth() && now.getDate()==dt.getDate()) {
                return df[1].format(dt);
            }
            return df[0].format(dt);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return datetime;
        }
    }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        String profileEmail = args.getString(DataProvider.COL_EMAIL);
        CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), 
                DataProvider.CONTENT_URI_MESSAGES, 
                null, 
                DataProvider.COL_FROM + " = ? or " + DataProvider.COL_TO + " = ?",
                new String[]{profileEmail, profileEmail}, 
                DataProvider.COL_AT + " DESC"); 
        return loader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        adapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        adapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

}
```

Output from logcat

```
03-06 16:52:05.729: E/AndroidRuntime(5419): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 16:52:05.729: E/AndroidRuntime(5419): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
03-06 16:52:05.729: E/AndroidRuntime(5419):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
03-06 16:52:05.729: E/AndroidRuntime(5419):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
03-06 16:52:05.729: E/AndroidRuntime(5419):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
03-06 16:52:05.729: E/AndroidRuntime(5419):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
03-06 16:52:05.729: E/AndroidRuntime(5419):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
03-06 16:52:05.729: E/AndroidRuntime(5419):     at com.xxxxx.yyyyy.FirstFragment.onCreateView(FirstFragment.java:38)
03-06 16:52:05.729: E/AndroidRuntime(5419):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
03-06 16:52:05.729: E/AndroidRuntime(5419):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
03-06 16:52:05.729: E/AndroidRuntime(5419):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
03-06 16:52:05.729: E/AndroidRuntime(5419):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
03-06 16:52:05.729: E/AndroidRuntime(5419):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
03-06 16:52:05.729: E/AndroidRuntime(5419):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:454)
03-06 16:52:05.729: E/AndroidRuntime(5419):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-06 16:52:05.729: E/AndroidRuntime(5419):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-06 16:52:05.729: E/AndroidRuntime(5419):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-06 16:52:05.729: E/AndroidRuntime(5419):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5136)
03-06 16:52:05.729: E/AndroidRuntime(5419):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-06 16:52:05.729: E/AndroidRuntime(5419):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-06 16:52:05.729: E/AndroidRuntime(5419):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-06 16:52:05.729: E/AndroidRuntime(5419):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-06 16:52:05.729: E/AndroidRuntime(5419):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-06 16:52:05.729: E/AndroidRuntime(5419): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.xxxxx.yyyyy.HomeActivity@419d4fa8 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
03-06 16:52:05.729: E/AndroidRuntime(5419):     at com.xxxxx.yyyyy.chat.MessagesFragment.onAttach(MessagesFragment.java:49)
03-06 16:52:05.729: E/AndroidRuntime(5419):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:848)
03-06 16:52:05.729: E/AndroidRuntime(5419):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1039)
03-06 16:52:05.729: E/AndroidRuntime(5419):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1141)
03-06 16:52:05.729: E/AndroidRuntime(5419):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4746)
03-06 16:52:05.729: E/AndroidRuntime(5419):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
03-06 16:52:05.729: E/AndroidRuntime(5419):     ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I see this lines in your layout code :

```
  android:layout_height="0dip"
  android:layout_weight="1"
```

`RelativeLayout` does not support `weight` attribute. Your `MessageFragment`'s height will always be 0. So you should set `layout_height` to `match_parent`.

Also if possible, post stack trace of your error.

Also you have used Fragment from support library in FirstFragment but not in MessageFragment. It must be a typo which need to be fixed or it will give you an error on devices with API less than 11.

Edit : It seems your `HomeActivity` is not implementing `OnFragmentInteractionListener`, which is throwing `ClassCastException` in onAttach callback.

Comment: So how to implement OnFragmentInteractionListener ? Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

call your `setListAdapter(adapter);` in `onActivityCreated()`

check the lifecycle methodes

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

onCreate() calls before initializing the fragment;

also chenge this

```
 View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.first_fragment,
            false);
```

Comment: have u tried setListAdapter(adapter); in onActivityCreated() ??

Answer (score 0):

In your `MessagesFragment`'s `onAttach`, your `com.xxxxx.yyyyy.HomeActivity` is passed in as activity.

Then, in the following code, you expect `HomeActivity` is also `OnFragmentInteractionListener`

```
mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
```

To solve this, you need to make your `HomeActivity`

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity implements OnFragmentInteractionListener
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will fix the problem, but I had one similar to it and I couldn't believe how easy it was to miss it / fix.
If you check your xml file, you will see your fragment labeled as:

```
<fragment 
        android:name="com.xxxxx.yyyyy.chat.MessagesFragment"
        android:id="@+id/msg_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Try simply capitalizing the 'f' in 'Fragment' so that the XML Auto complete will recognize that you likely mean a (android.support.v4.app.Fragment)